# What should I do when I received spam emails?

Tags: phishing, spam, outlook

I got these emails from a spammer to my inbox, I am not sure if these are phishing attempt. I can't tell.

[image]

Click on one of them, I see this
[image]

I checked the codes behind that mail, I see

```
smtp.mailfrom=YbAilGJazUvJpYoYlVS.cnrpxfkfvvmetdifzxgiyzrzc.fmfsruwjpipssifktxyexpnyatvsymfoz;
```

If I open those emails but do not click on any links, will I still be vulnerable?

What are the appropriate actions when we're in that kind of situation? We gotta select them and delete them somehow. at least ?

Comment: Selecting and deleting emails does not open them.

Comment: if you open emails that have images, you are just asking for trouble. I wouldn't open them at all regardless if you click anything or not.